# Monitoring a folder for files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-watchdog

Could you please tell me how can I implement the possibility of detecting two files with the same extension in a folder?

That is, I need a `folder` that will be tracked, and as soon as `two files` with the extension `.txt` appear in this `folder`, then it is necessary to identify the file created earlier than everyone else in the same folder (i.e. it will be the oldest) and display its `name` on the screen, for example, or any other `functions`.

I found this method that can track the creation of files in a `folder`... but unfortunately, the level of my knowledge of Python does not allow me to further develop the idea that I described above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        result = (event.event_type, event.src_path)
        print(result)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    path = r"/root/test/"
    event_handler = EventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your script:

```
import time
import os
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_created(event):
        action, path = (event.event_type, event.src_path)
        if not "." in path.split(os.sep)[-1]:
            return
        path = ".".join(path.split("."))
        extension = path.split(".")[-1]
        dirname = os.path.dirname(path)

        files = os.listdir(dirname)
        same_ext_files = [os.path.join(dirname, f) for f in files if f.endswith("." + extension)]
        creation_date = [os.path.getmtime(f) for f in same_ext_files]

        print(f"{action = }")
        print(f"{path = }")
        print(f"{extension = }")
        print(f"{dirname = }")
        print(f"{files = }")
        print(f"{same_ext_files = }")
        print(f"{creation_date = }")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    path = os.path.join("/root", "test/")
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        raise FileNotFoundError
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(EventHandler(), path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

[image]

Creating file `Fichier texte (2).txt`:

```
python test.py 
action = 'created'
path = '/home/vince/Bureau/stackoverflow/Fichier texte (2).txt'
extension = 'txt'
dirname = '/home/vince/Bureau/stackoverflow'
files = ['Fichier texte (2).txt', 'Fichier texte (1).txt', 'Fichier texte.txt', 'test.py']
same_ext_files = ['/home/vince/Bureau/stackoverflow/Fichier texte (2).txt', '/home/vince/Bureau/stackoverflow/Fichier texte (1).txt', '/home/vince/Bureau/stackoverflow/Fichier texte.txt']
creation_date = [1638378453.7645514, 1638378430.8448474, 1638378409.4784563]
```

You have now two lists: `same_ext_files` and `creation_date` to pipe to anything you want.

`code fixed to working`

Comment: great solution, thanks. and tell me, please, how to correctly specify any other directory for monitoring?

Comment: Now, if I instead: `path = os.path.dirname(__file__)` write this: `path = os.path.dirname('/root/test/')` then there will be an error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''`

Comment: the right command is `os.path.join("root", "test")`. This is cross platform pratice like this

Comment: can't figure it out, error again: `Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "/root/PycharmProjects/test.py", line 34, in <module> observer.start()`
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: I completely copied your code, run it, get it: `Traceback (most recent call last):`
 `File "/root/PycharmProjects/test.py"`, `line 33, in <module> raise FileNotFoundError`
`FileNotFoundError` line 33 - this `raise FileNotFoundError`

Comment: I realized the path should be like this: `path = os.path.join("/root", "test/")`. please correct it in your answer

Comment: there is still such a problem, when creating a file , the output is:
`action = 'created'`
`path = '/root/test/1'`
`extension = '/root/test/1'`
`dirname = '/root/test'`
`files = ['1.txt']`
`same_ext_files = []`
`creation_date = []`
The file extension, the correct path to it, and the creation date are not determined. What can be done about it? Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the problem is solved by changing the code to: `path = ".".join(path.split("."))`. please correct it in your answer

Comment: You have created a file without extension, I haven t check that, let me add a condition

Comment: `if not "." in path.slit(os.sep)[-1]:` - `slit` - are you sure? :)

Comment: It check if the filename contain an extension or not. (Not tested)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239778/discussion-between-alex-rebell-and-vincent-benet).